# Machine Learning Manual Labeling Quality

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a multi-label classification task.

There is a set of labels, when I evaluate the performance I see that in general all labels can be divided into two groups, labels with good performance and labels with bad performance and the gap between them is significant.

I am looking for an approach for how to evaluate the quality of the manual labeling. I know it's not trivial, but for sure I can do some investigation. For example, in good labels I see the that there is a set of attributes with a high weight that characterize these labels and for the labels with bad performance I do not see any good features.

What else can be done in order to see the differences between good labels and bad labels?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give any concrete advice without more details about your setup.

One method that is commonly used with crowd-sourced data is to ask multiple people for labels. If the labels are categorical in nature, only labels selected by the several labelers are used. If the labels are continuous they are usually averaged. You need to always contemplate the possibility that some labelers are either maliciously adding noise or don't fully understand the task.

You need to be careful, though. If your labeling is reasonable what the result of your experiment is telling you is that the attributes you have are not good at estimating the label. So, you may have a description problem more than a problem with the quality of the labels. These description problems are common in NLP and computer vision, for example where describing the objects of interest is difficult.

If you could add more about your data and what you want to accomplish and the results of your specific experiments I could add more specific advice.